# Opening password protected site (Passport.js) with Phantom.Js by setting cookie

Tags: cookies, express, mongoose, phantomjs, passport.js

I am trying to access a passport protected page of my **Express.js** app with a **Phantom.js** script.

How can I simulate a logged in user without knowing the passport?

I am using **Passport.js** as a auth library with *LocalStrategy* and *MongoStore* to safe the sessions in the *mongo* database. I am wondering if I can create a record in the *sessions* collection and set a generated cookie with **Phantom.js** (`phantom.addCookie(...)`) to simulate a specific logged in user without the password of the user?

Can I generate the content of the of the **connect.sid** cookie for a specific user in the backend and add it to phantom.js in order to simulate a logged in user?

### Findings:

I figured out that Passport.js uses the [**Cookie-Signature**](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-cookie-signature) node module to sign the cookie content and I assume **Express.js** uses the [**Connect**](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) *cookie* and *session* middleware to handle the cookie and session creation and insert them into the HTTP headers.

Comment: I think I found a solution, posting it later.

Comment: Could you post your solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

using javascript, you should be able to fill in your login fields and submit.  (simulating a user login, not trying to recreate a login cookie)

that would probably be your best bet.

for how to fill in forms, see: 
[How to fill in form field, and submit, using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683331/how-to-fill-in-form-field-and-submit-using-javascript)
[Automatic form fill using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932263/automatic-form-fill-using-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't work because I just have hashed passwords in the DB.

Comment: I actually found a solution, trying to write it down later.

Comment: @BausTheBig what's the solution?

Comment: @BausTheBig I'm using the session cookie (in fact, I'm using all the cookies in the request) and still not able to get authenticated by passport. Did you ever get this to work?