# iMacros - Filling form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, imacros

Ok well im running imacro on a website, filling forms with data, all forms are ok, but I still have a form which cannot accept any data entry with imacros

ALL OF THESE TAGS ARE RELATED TO THE FORM , AND THE SCRIPT CAN CLICK ON THE FORM WITH ANY OF THESE , BUT CANNOT FILL THE FORM WITH "CONTENTHERE"

```html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID::*.f CONTENT=CONTENTHERE
TAG POS=7 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=CONTENTHERE
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CONTENTEDITABLE* CONTENT=CONTENTHERE
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ROLE:textbox* CONTENT=CONTENTHERE
```

I tried the X and Y method to fill the form, but fails
I tried the Experimental event mode with firefox, but the form is dynamic and each time the attributes changes.
So the only remaining method is filling the form with javascript
I read these topics
[How to fill in form field, and submit, using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683331/how-to-fill-in-form-field-and-submit-using-javascript)
[Automatic form fill using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932263/automatic-form-fill-using-javascript)
But I'm not javascript developer, and I don't know how to use these javascript code to fill forms with my script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [XPath](http://wiki.imacros.net/XPATH)? Or maybe [EVENT](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT)?

It would be better if you could include the website URL here. Or maybe just put the HTML code somewhere.